# HERE maps crashes randomly

Tags: android, crash, here-api

I will open this because they might see it or somebody might had the same problem and figured it out. My app is using HERE maps integrated with AR functions and sometimes it randomly crashes with this message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.nokia.maps.ARLayoutControl com.nokia.maps.d.R()' on a null object reference
        at com.nokia.maps.am.a(CompositeFragmentImpl.java:129)
        at com.nokia.maps.am.a(CompositeFragmentImpl.java:52)
        at com.nokia.maps.am$1.onEngineInitializationCompleted(CompositeFragmentImpl.java:98)
        at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$10.run(MapsEngine.java:2499)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The code is obfuscated so there is nothing to get from the sources which makes sense. It is most likely lifecycle related as it happens when the user comes back from the map. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please share some further information about the SDK release you used here?

Comment: Hello, where do you get this information? There is nothing about this on the website. I generated this version a couple of weeks ago from our developer.here.com account.

Comment: There is a version.txt in the SDK package you downloaded. You will find the release there. Next to this can you also provide us some information about the device you were using for the test above and the Android version?